# Assign variable the result of a select statement

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

How would you assign a variable the result of a SELECT in Sql Server?

Here is my attempt:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE x
AS 
BEGIN

DECLARE @MyVar integer
DECLARE @sql nvarchar(150), @v nvarchar(50)
Set @v = 'mytable' 
--SET @sql = 'SELECT INTO ' + @MyVar + 'count(*) FROM ' + @v 
SET @sql = 'Set ' + @MyVar + '= SELECT count(*) FROM ' + @v 
EXEC sp_executesql @sql
print @MyVar
END
```

> *Conversion failed when converting the varchar value 'Set ' to data
>   type int.*

Any recommendation on learning the syntax would be useful too. Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use an `OUTPUT` parameter to `sp_executesql` as below.

```
DECLARE @MyVar INTEGER
DECLARE @sql NVARCHAR(MAX),
        @v   SYSNAME

SET @v = N'mytable'
SET @sql = N'SELECT @MyVar = count(*) FROM ' + QUOTENAME(@v)

EXEC sp_executesql
  @sql,
  N'@MyVar INT OUTPUT',
  @MyVar = @MyVar OUTPUT

PRINT @MyVar
```

RE: "Recommendation on learning the syntax" I don't really have one other than [books online](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/ms188001.aspx) but you should read [The Curse and Blessings of Dynamic SQL](http://www.sommarskog.se/dynamic_sql.html) to see why `QUOTENAME` is important.